# select con inner join y json_table

Tags: oracle, join

debo realizar una consulta de base de datos donde un campo de la tabla es de tipo CLOB y almacena una estructura json, la consulta de la estructura y como mapearla no tiene inconveniente, sin embargo la tabla tiene otros campos con llaves foraneas las cuales requiero hacer joins, pero al realizar el join se presenta error que indica que los identificadores de la tabla en la cual se realiza el inner join no son validos.

```
select t1.campo0, t0.campo0, t0.campo1, jt.*
from tabla0 t0, 
json_table( ... ) jt
inner join tabla1 t1 on t0.id = t1.id_fk
where ...
```

Al ejecutar la consulta los identificadores no validos corresponden a los de t0.id

El error es el siguiente:

```
ORA-00904 : "t0"."id" : identificador no válido
00904. 0000 "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Este error solo se presenta cuando adiciono el bloque de codigo
`json_table(...) jt`, si lo quito no presenta error, pero requiero ese bloque de código en la consulta

Agradezco de su colaboración para determinar el por que del error y como puedo hacer el join correspondiente.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el mensaje exacto de error?

Comment: Edite la pregunta con el detalle del error. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ya fue solucionado el problema es que la sentencia `from` se desconecta de los `inner join`, entonces lo que realice fue colocar el `inner join` previo a la sentencia `json_table`

```
select t1.campo0, t0.campo0, t0.campo1, jt.*
from tabla0 t0
inner join tabla1 t1 on t0.id = t1.id_fk,
json_table( ... ) jt
where ...
```

acá ya funciona.